# django-allauth Registering a site for API Keys

Tags: django, api-key, django-allauth

I'm starting out with django and am working on implementing django-allauth to my site.

Key ones I'm interested in:

- Google
- LinkedIn
- Facebook

As I understand it I need to register my application with each of the providers in order to get API keys and tokens.

On these provider sites, when registering an application it is asking for the project name and the project URL.

Question is if I want to at first run my site on my local machine, do I need to register my localhost separately? If so, what should the project name and project URL be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the localhost in your social apps, for example in `Facebook App`:

```
Display Name: My project
Namespace: myproject_test
Site URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000
Canvas URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Secure Canvas URL: https://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

And when you deploy your site you have to change the settings according to your domain on which you host your site.

In `django-allauth` after getting the `Key` and `Secret` of your app you have to login to admin in your project and go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/socialaccount/socialapp/` to add the provider there before using it.

Comment: Cool thanks Aamir. Will try that. There was mention of using callback url somewhere for redirect. Is that on the Facebook, Google API side?